# Is it possible to set up conditional formats using Excel Online?

Tags: conditional-formatting, excel-online

Is it possible to set up conditional formats using Excel Online?

The cell's context menu doesn't have the option, and I can't find it in the ribbon either.

Answer (score 2):

I have just been using an online Excel spreadsheet and it is now possible to setup conditional formatting in Online Excel.

[image: Screen shot slice of online excel]

Comment: Hi Martlark, thanks for your answer.  Could you link to some documentation on this change in the body of your answer?

Answer (score 1):

### ```
Support: YES
Set up:  NO
Edit:    NO
```

Excel Online supports **Conditional Formatting** with **Data Bars**, **Color Scales** and **Icon Sets**. Select a range to be formatted, and go to **Home > Conditional Formatting > Pick your style**. If you need to clear an existing format you can choose the **Clear Rules** option.

If you want to apply other Conditional Formatting options, and have the Excel desktop application, you can use it to add and change conditional formatting.

After making changes and saving your workbook in Excel desktop application, you'll see the changes when you reopen it in Excel Online.

[image]

**[https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/apply-or-change-conditional-formatting-af691895-1cb2-4a6e-9ca6-2143ca97322d)**

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. [Conditional formatting may be viewed but not applied in Excel Online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/excel-online-service-description.aspx).

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It does. If your browser is shown on a big screen, it is directly in the ribbon’s Home tab:

[image: expanded ribbon for big screens]

If you are using a smaller screen, it is hidden under the Tables category in the Home tab:

[image: collapsed ribbon for small screens]

The blog post [“Excel for the Web”](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/excel-for-the-web/ba-p/1522225) posted on 2020-07-15 documents that this feature was added to “Excel for Web” (Excel Online) in the first half of 2020. The support article [“What's new in Excel for the web” in section “Released in 2020”](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-new-in-excel-for-the-web-f8f98d6b-4752-4119-a2aa-4de22ece8d81) lists this feature.